# Обработка значений массива

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$m = array('1', '2', '3' .... '18');
```

каждое значение которого нужно обработать функцией iconv:

```
iconv ('windows-1251', 'utf-8', значение массива);
```

как это сделать?

Comment: Извините, а зачем? Цифры как в cp1251, так в ascii и utf-8 имеют одинаковый код. Если бы там были не ascii символы -- дело другое. А обработка -- `foreach`

Comment: цыфры для примера, вообще русский текст там

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну блин, а подумать ???

```
foreach($m as &$a) {
    $a = iconv ('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $a);
}
```

ну разве так трудно ?

Comment: ну не совсем это нужно, если точнее, как пользоваться потом этими значениями, ну, например, что-то типа `$a[0] $a[1] ... $a[18]`

Comment: foreach(...){...} 

**var_dump($m)**

Answer (score 2):

```
function func($a){return iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $a);}
array_map('func', $m);
```

Хотя мне больше нравится вариант через foreach.

Comment: .

    $m = array_map(function($a) {
        return iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $a); 
    }, $m);

Answer (score 1):

Пойдем в лобовую!

```
$test = iconv ('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $a['0']);
echo $test;
```

Хотя, по секрету, первый ответ более православный ;)