# Аргументы функции, передаваемые по ссылке в PHP

Tags: php

Вот только сегодня (23.01.2012), читая [Хабрахабр](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/136835/), статья меня несколько обескуражила. Кроме того заметил, что, видимо, опытные программисты здесь, на ХэшКод"е так же пользуются следующей конструкцией ([сей вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73624/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)):

```
foreach($m as &$a) {
    $a = iconv ('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $a);
}
```

Во-первых, не совсем понятно зачем? Насколько помнится, следующий код в PHP так же будет верен:

```
foreach($m as $a) {
    $a = iconv ('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $a);
}
```

Во-вторых, из статьи на Хабре я не понял, каким образом другой программист (напр. Петрович) сможет как-то повлиять на переменную `&$a`, как в нашем случае. Неужто в PHP действие этой переменной распространяется на весь дальнейший код? Т.е. область видимости не ограничивается циклом `foreach`?

В-третьих, я бы не стал в столь простом примере, тем более начинающему, давать такую "тонкость" на вооружение. Ибо как сказано на том же Хабре, с этим путаются сейчас даже "бывалые", в какой-то степени, программисты.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых: До 5.2(могу врать) цикл foreach в части as делал что-то вроде "`$a = $m[$i];`", т.е. создавал копию переменной. После появилась возможность объявлять ссылкой. */ *В функцию, к слову, до сих пор обычным путем нельзя передать неопределенное кол-во ссылочных аргументов.* /*

Соответственно:

```
$m = array(1, 1, 1, 1);
foreach ($m as $a) $a += 1; // --> $a = $m[$i]; $a++;
print_r($m);// 1, 1, 1, 1
foreach ($m as &$a) $a += 1;
print_r($m);// 2, 2, 2, 2
```

Далее, (во-вторых) область видимости в php ограничивается только совсем явно - неймспейсами, методами и функциями.

```
$m = array(1, 1, 1, 1);
$a = 0;
function a() { $a++; echo $a; }
a(); // notice: undefined...
while ($a < 10) echo ++$a; // 1, 2, 3 ... 10
echo $a; // 10
foreach ($m as $b)
  $c = $b+3;
echo $c; // 4
```

Циклы, свитчи, условия и даже вложенность файлов никак на область видимости не влияют. Возможно, поэтому многие вызывают шаблоны из функции, дабы верстала чего не зацепил (при этом всегда есть массив `$GLOBALS`=) )

В-третьих, бывалые редко путаются, ибо набита привычка переменные проверять и переопределять. А новичкам в php вообще трудно (легко г-кодить, трудно понимать), ибо нужен больше опыт, чем разум.

ЗЫ: В результате хабровского случая виноваты два нуба, а не ссылки. Вижу попытку обвинить револьвер в выстреле в ногу.

ЗЗЫ: + к во-вторых, такой случай возможен, если область видимости не ограничивалась вообще.

```
// file1
$items = array( /* ... */);

//file2
foreach ($items as &$item) $item = /* ... */;

//file3
foreach ($items as &$item) $item = /* ... */;

//file4
require 'file1.php';
require 'file2.php';
require 'file3.php';
```

Comment: Предельно все просто. И кое-где даже логично. Спасибо.

> цикл foreach в части as делал что-то вроде "$a = $m[$i];"

Странно, что он не делал что-то вроде `$a = &$m[$i];`, как на мой взгляд, это было бы логичнее. Не правда-ли?

Comment: Вот именно в этом месте можно начинать читать цитаты автора php) Просто во всей литературе пишут либо for с обращением по индексу, либо `foreach ($m as $n => $a) $m[$n] += 2;`, причем пишут так спокойно, что вопроса "а, собственно, нафиг тут `$a`?" не возникает. Просто очередной костыль, который надо знать и учитывать в коде. А так да, конечно было бы логичнее, причем переменную unset'ить автоматом)) Но - стена крепче головы)

Answer (score 1):

Пример на хабре не очень показательный. Проблема вовсе не в области видимости и не в том, что после цикла `$item` продолжает ссылаться на последний элемент массива.

Основная проблема заключается в том, что любые операции передачи по ссылке *влияют на оба операнда*. Если вы пишете `$item =& $array[0];`, вы затрагиваете не только `$item`, но и `$array`. Об этом нужно всегда помнить, работая с ссылками в PHP.

Приведу более наглядный пример:

```
$foo = array(1, 2, 3);

foreach($foo as &$item) {
    $item += 1;
}
// далее идет 100500 строк кода

// мы же помним, что массивы в php передаются по значению?
$bar = $foo;

// далее $foo и $bar могут "гулять" по коду
// передаваться в другие функции и находится в разных namespaces...

// ...пока однажды:
$bar[2] = 42;

// уже догадались, что произошло с $foo?
var_dump($foo);
```

Т.ч. в результате хабровского случая, виноват именно первый программист, который не сделал `unset()` после цикла и тем самым оставил после себя минное поле, которое в будущем аукнется самыми "мистическими" ошибками.

Comment: Кстати, не хочу вопрос отдельный создавать, ибо эта же тема: что делать, если надо присвоить значение переменной, в которой уже ссылка? Без unset в частности.

    $a = array(1, 1, 1, 1);
    $b = &$a[1];
    // как сделать, чтоб $b стало 5, а $a[1] не изменился?

и еще смешная штука: 

    $varname = 'v'.rand(1, 9999);
    $$varname = new stdClass;
    $obj = $$varname;
    unset($varname);
    // как здесь уничтожить объект? :)

Comment: У переменной будет убран флаг `is_ref`, когда счетчик ссылок на нее уменьшится до 1. Т.е. в данном примере надо сделать `unset($b);`, а затем уже `$b = 5;`. Без unset никак не сделать.

Comment: Во втором случае разве что как-то так:

    foreach ($GLOBALS as $k => $v) {
        if ($k != 'obj' && $v === $obj) {
            unset($GLOBALS[$k]);
        }
    }
    unset($v, $obj);